# Can modifiers be called in the Game Engine?

Tags: game-engine, modifiers

Can modifiers be called in the Blender Game engine and called using actuators?

For example, could the explode modifier be called when you jump on a box?

If so, are there some modifiers that work better than others (faster rendering), or any general rules of thumb I should use when applying them?

Comment: I know that the generate modifiers (mirror, array, subsurface division) work just fine in the Blender Game engine. I think that all of the other modifiers could be used as well. It's just a question of whether the graphics card will be able to handle them in real time.

Comment: It's better to have animations done beforehand and then use an action actuator.

Comment: @iKlsR good point. Still would like to know though. I haven't done much in the GE since 2.4x.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While certain mesh modifiers like subdiv and array modifiers works* in the game engine, modifiers cannot be called while you are in the game engine. (i.e. you cannot create an explode or array modifier using actuators)

*Actually, I would suggest baking the mesh modifiers anyway before you run the game. Otherwise you might run into [physics bounding box issues](http://projects.blender.org/tracker/?func=detail&aid=23894&group_id=9&atid=306).